# I want to show last 10 years in wordpress posts with shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I want to show 2022 in [year1], 2021 in [year2], 2020 in [year3] so on up to last 10 years. got this code from chatGPT but its showing current year for all [year1], [year2], ...[[year10] shortcodes. whats the solution ?

```
function year_shortcode($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'num' => '1'
        ),
        $atts
    );

    $num = intval($atts['num']);

    if ($num >= 1 && $num <= 10) {
        $current_year = intval(date('Y'));
        $year = $current_year - $num + 1;
        return $year;
    }

    return ''; // Return an empty string if the provided 'num' attribute is not valid
}

add_shortcode('year1', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year2', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year3', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year4', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year5', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year6', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year7', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year8', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year9', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year10', 'year_shortcode');
```

Comment: ChatGPT is the worst. This is creating 10 different shortcodes. Why not create one shortcode and pass the year you want as an argument to the shortcode?

Comment: yeah, but next year it should change to next year - 1, next year -2, next year-3 ..so on. automatically.

please share me the code

Answer (score 0):

This is an [XY Problem](https://www.xyproblem.info), but if you really want 10 shortcodes that all callback the same function rather than one shortcode that passes the year:

```
// Shortcode callbacks have three arguments: attributes, content and shortcode tag.
function year_shortcode($atts, $content, $tagname) {
    // remove the word "year"
    $year_num = str_replace('year', '', $tagname);
    // Convert the number string to an int.
    $num = (int)$year_num;

    if ($num >= 1 && $num <= 10) {
        $current_year = intval(date('Y'));
        $year = $current_year - $num + 1;
        return $year;
    }

    return ''; 
}

add_shortcode('year1', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year2', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year3', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year4', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year5', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year6', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year7', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year8', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year9', 'year_shortcode');
add_shortcode('year10', 'year_shortcode');
```

This should work, but not tested.